How can I populate a VR soft keyboard (Meta Quest Browser) with existing text?
If I am in VR (Meta Quest) using the Oculus Browser app and the page has an HTML text input field, when I press on the field to give it focus the keyboard comes up underneath. I type, it works.  I can edit the text, it works.  Great.
When I am in VR experience, I press on the field and the virtual keyboard pops into the world and I can type and edit the field.  A little text field on the top of the keyboard also shows what I am typing.  Great.
But... if I press off the field and lose focus, then press on the field again, the little text field on the top of the keyboard does not receive the current text.  And if I start typing again, it clears the real text field and starts all over again.  This seems like a bug.
How can I populate the soft keyboard's current text when I press on a field in a VR experience.
